# How to use custom fonts in Google Maps marker's InfoWindowText?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

How can I custom font of marker `infoWindowText` on [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter)?
Here is my add Marker code:

```
mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
            zIndex: list.id.toDouble(),
            position: LatLng(double.parse(list.lat), double.parse(list.long)),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/marker.png"),
            infoWindowText:
                InfoWindowText(list.name))
```

Comment: Which version are you using for  `google_maps_flutter` plugin ? is it the latest one ?`^0.4.0`

Comment: I used `google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3`

Comment: the plugin change a lot, there is no any `MarkerOptions`, [some breaking change happend you can see the change log](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#-changelog-tab-)

Comment: How can I set default font for app ? It's mean my app just only using one font.

Comment: You can visit this page for [default font for the whole app](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) , It might affect the `InfoWindowText` too.

Comment: Edit my answer this one may work for you (Edit 2)

Comment: Did you handle your problem/case @Alex ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have that version but you can give a shot with `DefaultTextStyle` widget wrap your `InfoWindowText` widget with `DefaultTextStyle`

Edit 2 =>
**or you can try to wrap the related class/page/scaffold which contains your `map` with `DefaultTextStyple`:**

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('default style 1'),
        Text('default style 2')
      ],
      ));
```

on the other hand,

I would recommend to upgrade the latest version of the `google_maps_flutter` plugin which is `^0.4.0` right now, but you need to [Migrate to AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) because of this breaking change

[image]

lastly in the last version of this plugin, you have a `Marker` and `infoWindow` property

```
    Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(stepIndex.toString()),
        position: LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude),
        infoWindow:
            InfoWindow(title: stepIndex.toString(), snippet: explanation));
```

`InfoWindow` accepts a string for `title` and `snippet` properties so I don't think we can change the text style.

**edit :** 
as you think you can try to change whole app text font [using custom fonts](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)